# Trying to invert binary image gives me full black screen

Tags: image, verilog

I have a black and white image that I would like to invert (black to white and white to black), where black = 0 and white = 255. I am trying to use the code below, but rather than inverting the image I have, it just makes the entire screen black.

```
module Inverter (
    input   [7:0]   binary_red,
    input   [7:0]   binary_green,
    input   [7:0]   binary_blue,
    output  [7:0]   inverted_red,
    output  [7:0]   inverted_green,
    output  [7:0]   inverted_blue);

    parameter black = 0;
    parameter white = 255;

    assign inverted_red = (binary_red == black) ? white : black;
    assign inverted_green = (binary_green == black) ? white : black;
    assign inverted_blue = (binary_blue == black) ? white : black;
endmodule
```

Any ideas as to why this is not inverting like I want it to? Thanks for the help!

EDIT: So some people asked to see more code, as it might not be this module that is screwing it up. There is a color filter that takes in raw RGB data and filters out for only red first:

```
module  Color_Filter (
    input       [9:0]   oVGA_Red,
    input       [9:0] oVGA_Green,
    input   [9:0]   oVGA_Blue,
    output  [7:0]   filtered_Red,
    output  [7:0]   filtered_Green,
    output  [7:0]   filtered_Blue);

    parameter redFilterValue = 150;
    parameter greenFilterValue = 110;
    parameter blueFilterValue = 110;

    assign  filtered_Red = (oVGA_Red[9:2] >= redFilterValue && oVGA_Green[9:2] <= greenFilterValue && oVGA_Blue[9:2] <= blueFilterValue) ? oVGA_Red[9:2] : 0;
    assign  filtered_Green = (oVGA_Red[9:2] >= redFilterValue && oVGA_Green[9:2] <= greenFilterValue && oVGA_Blue[9:2] <= blueFilterValue) ? oVGA_Green[9:2] : 0;
    assign  filtered_Blue = (oVGA_Red[9:2] >= redFilterValue && oVGA_Green[9:2] <= greenFilterValue && oVGA_Blue[9:2] <= blueFilterValue) ? oVGA_Blue[9:2] : 0;

endmodule
```

After this it gets converted to grayscale using the code below:

```
module  Greyscale_Filter    (
    input       [7:0]   filtered_red,
    input       [7:0]   filtered_green,
    input       [7:0]   filtered_blue,
    output  [7:0]   greyscale_red,
    output  [7:0]   greyscale_green,
    output  [7:0]   greyscale_blue);

    assign greyscale_red = (filtered_red != 0) ? (299*filtered_red/1000)+(587*filtered_green/1000)+(114*filtered_blue/1000) : 0;
    assign greyscale_green = (filtered_green != 0) ? (299*filtered_red/1000)+(587*filtered_green/1000)+(114*filtered_blue/1000) : 0;
    assign greyscale_blue = (filtered_blue != 0) ? (299*filtered_red/1000)+(587*filtered_green/1000)+(114*filtered_blue/1000) : 0;

endmodule
```

Then it goes to a binary image where it looks at the value of the greyscale and converts to binary based upon its value, seen below:

```
module Binary_Filter (
    input   [7:0]   greyscale_red,
    input       [7:0]   greyscale_green,
    input       [7:0]   greyscale_blue,
    output  [7:0] binary_red,
    output  [7:0] binary_green,
    output  [7:0]   binary_blue);

    parameter black = 0;
    parameter white = 255;

    assign binary_red = ((greyscale_red > 51) ? white : black); 
    assign binary_green = ((greyscale_green > 51) ? white : black); 
    assign binary_blue = ((greyscale_blue > 51) ? white : black); 

endmodule
```

After this it goes to the invert module I originally posted. In my top level module this is done by doing:

```
Color_Filter    color_filter    (
                                    .oVGA_Red(oVGA_R),
                                    .oVGA_Green(oVGA_G),
                                    .oVGA_Blue(oVGA_B),
                                    .filtered_Red(filtered_R),
                                    .filtered_Green(filtered_G),
                                    .filtered_Blue(filtered_B)
                                    );

Greyscale_Filter    greyscale_Filter    (
                                            .filtered_red(filtered_R),
                                            .filtered_green(filtered_G),
                                            .filtered_blue(filtered_B),
                                            .greyscale_red(greyscale_R),
                                            .greyscale_blue(greyscale_G),
                                            .greyscale_green(greyscale_B)
                                            );

Binary_Filter   binary_filter   (
                                    .greyscale_red(greyscale_R),
                                    .greyscale_green(greyscale_G),
                                    .greyscale_blue(greyscale_B),
                                    .binary_red(binary_R),
                                    .binary_green(binary_G),
                                    .binary_blue(binary_B)
                                    );

Inverter    inverter    (
                    .clk(VGA_CTRL_CLK),
                    .binary_red(binary_R),
                    .binary_green(binary_G),
                    .binary_blue(binary_B),
                    .inverted_red(inverted_R),
                    .inverted_green(inverted_G),
                    .inverted_blue(inverted_B)
                    );
```

Comment: Do you really have binary image (1 bit per pixel) or simply a black-and-white image?

Comment: I guess it is technically a black-and-white image. I do color filtering to find red light and then anywhere that is red, I set the three color channels to 255 (white) and anywhere that isn't goes to 0 (black)

Comment: Your input might not be pure black and white, but have shades of gray. For example if `binary_red` was 1 (near black), then `inverted_red` would be 0 (black), not 254 (near white).  Try bit inverting with the `~` operator: ex `assign inverted_red = ~binary_red;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input data might not be pure black and white, but have shades of gray. For example, if `binary_red` was 1 (near black), then `inverted_red` would be 0 (black), not 254 (near white).

Try bit inverting with the `~` operator.

```
assign inverted_red = ~binary_red;
assign inverted_green = ~binary_green;
assign inverted_blue = ~binary_blue;
```

---

Everything shown so far is for a single pixel, not the entire array. Best debugging advice anyone can give at this point is for you to test each stages and isolate the issue. Make sure the filter gives the correct output, then the grey-scale filter, then binary filter, and finally the inverted.

Also make try to run in simulation where you can see all the internal signals in waveform before putting an FPGA. A very simple test environment example: http://www.edaplayground.com/x/KqX

Comment: I'm not sure. I set binary_red, green and blue by first taking a greyscale image and checking its value at each pixel. If its gray value is above 100 (not super black), it sets it to 0, otherwise it sets it to 255. So I think all the values would be 0 or 255, right?

Comment: @Mike: it's wrong approach. You should write a module that will work for all possible values (`0-255`) and Greg solution is a good way to do that.

Comment: @Greg: I went ahead and tried doing this and still got a completely black screen (using the ~ operator).

Comment: @Mike: the issue may not be with the Inverter module. You'll need to share more code.

Comment: Figured it out. I was flipping the front and back porches as well which caused the whole image to go to black. Just had to constrain it to just the pixels on the screen (640x480 in this case)